# CSS3 Columns Block out specific column(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div divided into three columns using CSS3

```
.div {column-count: 3;}
```

This div contains a string of text which fills some part of the columns.

Can anyone think of a way to block out one or more of these columns?

So for example the first column is blocked and the text begins at the top of the second column.

The height of the div is unknown and changes.

The div is also contenteditable.

Comment: This sounds like you are misusing/misunderstanding CSS columns. Can you give more information, on why you want this, or what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: It's so the user can input text into this 'author' tool, and some layouts specify that some columns should be blocked. The layouts have to be flexible so the blocked column(s) can be changed on the fly.

Comment: The web isn't desktop publishing, so specific features like that aren't really possible. Why do you want to allow users to block columns in the first place? You could not use CSS columns, but split the text server-side into "equal" parts and render the columns yourself, but splitting text like that isn't trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I ended up doing it was if I wanted to block the left column I would apply `padding-left` equal to one column's width, take down the `width` equal to one column's width and change `column-count` to 2.

If I wanted to block the middle column I would change `column-count` to 2 and set the `column-gap` equal to the width of one column plus the existing column gap.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Blueprint CSS. It's a framework that can be used to easily create complex multi-column layouts.

http://www.blueprintcss.org/

This link can help you get started: http://www.cssbakery.com/2012/06/using-blueprint-css-framework.html

Also, column-count works only in opera. For Firefox supports -moz-column-count, whereas Chrome and Safari support -webkit-column-count.

Godspeed.

Comment: I don't think this will work with HTML5 contenteditable the same way CSS3 columns work, unless I'm wrong?